# PHP word xml parsing

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I'm trying to create the xml file from the Microsoft word file. I saved the word file as XML. But unable to parse it or get the content form it. It shows like below

```
<wx:sect><w:p wsp:rsidR="00537F3C" wsp:rsidRPr="00616B5B" wsp:rsidRDefault="005F2CBA" wsp:rsidP="005F2CBA"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Contents"/></w:pPr><w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00616B5B"><w:t>Contents</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p wsp:rsidR="001E54C8" wsp:rsidRDefault="001E54C8"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="TOC2"/><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:h-ansi="Calibri"/><wx:font wx:val="Calibri"/><w:b w:val="off"/><w:i-cs w:val="off"/><w:noProof/><w:kern w:val="0"/><w:sz w:val="22"/><w:sz-cs w:val="22"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/></w:r><w:r><w:instrText> TOC \o "1-9" \t "ActHead 1,2,ActHead 2,2,ActHead 3,3,ActHead 4,4,ActHead 5,5, Schedule,2, Schedule Text,3, NotesSection,6" </w:instrText></w:r><w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:t>Chapter 1—Introduction and core provisions</w:t></w:r> .....
```

How to get the content like title, subsection, part and others. I tried with below code

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('ITA97Vol01_1-36_WD02_2.xml');


    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('sect') as $child) {
        echo "<pre>";print_R($child);
        echo "</pre>";  

    }
```

Is there any pattern to get the required data. Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: sect is in namesapace aliased wx, try reading the element with its namespace

Comment: @TomerW Can you Explain or any Sample Code sir

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php

Comment: @TomerW Thaks. I ll look at on this

Comment: @TomerW I think that link referes for the xml strings. If i use that for file it returns empty only. Can you help me

Comment: i m on my cell, so i cant create an example... in general, either read more about xml NS, or use ByName 'wx:sect' should work as well.

Comment: @TomerW i ll try with use ByName. Please create an example when you are free sir

Comment: @TomerW getElementsByName is undefined method sir

Answer (score 0):

what Tomer W suggested is replacing your `getElementsByTagName` with the `getElementsByTagNameNS`function. I can't tell the Word version from your xml snippet, but you will need the namespace for your wx:sect tags. so somewhere above in your xml you should have `xmlns:wx="http://schemas...."` - so just copy that url for the NS based TagName function:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('ITA97Vol01_1-36_WD02_2.xml');


foreach($xml->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://schemas....','sect') as $child) {
    echo "<pre>";print_R($child);
    echo "</pre>";  

}
```

Whereas with the titles, i assume that you are referring to the titles you have used in the first line of each section. Titles are also just stored in plain `<w:t>...</w:t>` tags, so you either select first occurrence of *t* element following a new section, or you will have to find the header style first and then select text there.

But for a full solution you will have to dig through the complete file, there is a lot of garbage around there so you should only orientate by known elements/tags.